# Omit certain post from loop- Wordpress

Tags: loops, foreach, wordpress, foreach-loop-container

I have two loops on custom page, I want from the second loop to omit the post with Post ID from the first loop (of course show all other posts from category 36).

Edit: this is the whole code in the php file:

```
<?php
global $udesign_options;

// construct an array of portfolio categories
$portfolio_categories_array = explode( ',', $udesign_options['portfolio_categories'] );

if ( $portfolio_categories_array != "" && post_is_in_category_or_descendants( $portfolio_categories_array ) ) :
// Test if this Post is assigned to the Portfolio category or any descendant and switch the single's template accordingly
include 'single-Portfolio.php';
else : // Continue with normal Loop (Blog category)

get_header();

$content_position = ( $udesign_options['blog_sidebar'] == 'left' ) ? 'grid_16 push_8' : 'grid_16';
if ( $udesign_options['remove_single_sidebar'] == 'yes' ) $content_position = 'grid_24';
?>
<div id="content-container" class="container_24">
<div id="main-content" class="<?php echo $content_position; ?>">
    <div class="main-content-padding">
<?php if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="entry" style="margin:-30px 0 00px 0;">
<?php                           // Post Image
                            if( $udesign_options['display_post_image_in_single_post'] == 'yes' ) display_post_image_fn( $post->ID, false );
            the_content(__('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>', 'udesign'));
            wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>


            </div>


<?php
$args = array( 'category' => 36, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );    
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>     
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> 
<?php the_content(); ?> 
<?php echo do_shortcode('[divider_top]'); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?> 



<div><?php comments_template();
        endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e("Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.", 'udesign'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?></div>
    </div><!-- end main-content-padding -->
</div><!-- end main-content -->

<?php
if( ( !$udesign_options['remove_single_sidebar'] == 'yes' ) && sidebar_exist('BlogSidebar') ) { get_sidebar('BlogSidebar'); }
?>

</div><!-- end content-container -->
<?php endif; // end normal Loop ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I figured it out, this code needs to be inserted $args = array('exclude' =>theExcludedID, 'category' => 36, 'post_type' => 'post' );

Comment: ¿Where are the queries? I see the arguments array ($args) in the second loop, but where are BOTH queries?

Comment: there arent any queries. This is all the code. It is working, but the first post is repeated in the second loop.

Comment: Now I see them. It is done with `get_posts()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Can you provide the code please

Comment: ¿How do you get the posts for the first loop? For the second loop it's clear that they are fetched with `get_posts()` function but for the first one, the code is missing. ¿Are they from category 36 also, for example? Impossible to guess.

Comment: Oh, you are right.. Sorry. Yes they are also from category 36. It is the standard Wordpress Loop I guess, since it is default in the U-design theme. This gets the posts I think: <?php if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: If they are from the same category without exceptions, then all posts for that category are processed in the first loop and there is nothing left for second loop, unless there is a filter for the first loop. That's why you should update your question with the relevant code before the first loop.

Comment: OK, I updated my question with the full php file

Comment: Felipe, do you have any idea or are you bluffing? :)

Comment: I am not. Check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question's update, it seems the first loop displays all categories in `portfolio_categories` from a custom query, most probably including those from category 36 also.

The only way I can think off to not repeat the posts in the second loop is to exclude all category 36 posts from the first loop.

I can't test the code, but here is an idea of how to do it:

Add 3 lines of code after the Loop, like this:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // This is the Loop
$Category =  get_the_category( $post->ID );
$CatID = $Category[0]->cat_ID ; // The 0 assumes the post has only one category. If there are more, the number must be changed accordingly.
if ($CatID == 36) continue;
```

Comment: this could work, but how would I then dynamically display the first post? Correct syntax is the line with $args in the second loop replaced with $args = array('exclude' =>$post->ID, 'category' => 36, 'post_type' => 'post' );

Comment: The way it is in the code, no need to modify it. It will fetch and display all posts in category 36, excluded in the previous loop with the suggested modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following at the top of your loop:

```
if(get_the_ID() == theExcludedID){
    continue;
}
```

To skip any iteration.

Comment: the first or the second loop? Seems like it does not work when I put it before $args = array ....

Comment: Wherever you want to skip should the ID match, place it just before